# SQL Server Search Multiple columns of different datatypes with one Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, sql-server-2012

So I have a table on a front end that is linked into my SQL Server backend. I can do paging and everything from there.

I'm trying to implement a good search function that can retrieve data across a variety of different columns the table has.

There is only one search bar, so I cannot search on each individual column separately.

An example of fields I have are

```
Field #
Requestor
Case #
Device Model
Submit Date
```

For whatever search term the user types in, using SQL Server I need to be able to search all the searchable columns and return rows where that value is similar to the search term.

I'm not sure how to begin or start with this, and how to also make it performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like `select * from table where field# like '%input%' or requestor like %input% or case# like '%input%'`... but I would recommend taking a look at [sql full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: SQL Full-Text-Search worked out the best. It's working fast for me and I can search each of the columns easily. Thanks!